Axum + TLS | How to specify config?
Before axum I've worked with rust rocket framework. Rocket provides special file Rocket.toml where configuration can be specified. In there I wrote key and certs paths, but how to do the same in axum?
I have checked axum's examples and tried to use axum-server, but it looks like dead? I got an error with dependecies and don't know how to fix that. Even i don't know is there any sense to create an issue in axum-server repo.
If someone knows the different way - it would be great!
Error:
Copying platform assembly files from C:/Users/*/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/aws-lc-sys-0.24.0/aws-lc/generated-src/win-x86_64/crypto/ to D:/Rust/test-repo/target/debug/build/aws-lc-sys-5c959976a3609b0f/out/build/aws-lc/crypto
  mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'aws-lc/crypto/CMakeFiles/crypto_objects.dir/chacha/chacha-x86_64.asm.obj', needed by 'artifacts/libaws_lc_0_24_0_crypto.a'.  Stop.
  mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:272: aws-lc/crypto/CMakeFiles/crypto.dir/all] Error 2
  mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2
  thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\*\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\cmake-0.1.52\src/lib.rs:1115:5:


Here is a minimal example using either tls-rustls or tls-openssl with axum-server.
/*
[dependencies.axum]
version = ">=0"
default-features = false

[dependencies.axum-server]
version = ">=0"
default-features = false
features = ["tls-rustls", "tls-openssl"] # choose only one of these

[dependencies.tokio]
version = ">=0"
default-features = false
features = ["rt-multi-thread"]
*/

async fn get_root() -> axum::response::Response {
    let content_type = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    let content = r#"<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head><body>
    <hr><h2>Hello</h2><hr>
    </body></html>
    "#;
    axum::response::Response::builder()
        .status(axum::http::StatusCode::OK)
        .header(axum::http::header::CONTENT_TYPE, content_type)
        .body(content.into())
        .unwrap()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let port_number = 9988_u16;
    let bind_addr = std::net::SocketAddr::from((
        std::net::Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED,
        port_number,
    ));
    //
    let app = axum::Router::new().route("/", axum::routing::get(get_root));
    //
    let cert_file = std::path::Path::new("cert.pem");
    let key_file = std::path::Path::new("key.pem");
    //
    if std::env::args().any(|a| a == "ssl") {
        println!("using openssl on port {}", port_number);
        let ssl_config =
            axum_server::tls_openssl::OpenSSLConfig::from_pem_file(
                cert_file, key_file,
            )
            .unwrap();
        let server = axum_server::bind_openssl(bind_addr, ssl_config);
        server.serve(app.into_make_service()).await.unwrap();
    } else {
        println!("using rustls on port {}", port_number);
        let tls_config =
            axum_server::tls_rustls::RustlsConfig::from_pem_file(
                cert_file, key_file,
            )
            .await
            .unwrap();
        let server = axum_server::bind_rustls(bind_addr, tls_config);
        server.serve(app.into_make_service()).await.unwrap();
    }
}


Could you provide concrete versions for the dependencies? version = ">=0" is not helpful in the long run.

Your example doesn't work. As I mention before, there is a problem with axum-server library. Something wrong with dependencies. When I'm trying to run my program via cargo run, I got an error with cmake (I've added it to my question)

I thought the question was « Axum + TLS | How to specify config? », but it seems (after the edit) to be actually « cmake cannot compile aws-lc on my computer ». Sorry, I have no clue, it works out of the box for me.

@prog-fh yep. And before the edit I have pinned a link to a git repo for the same issue. Idk how it works for u, but for me, after enabling tls-rustls feature, code cannot even build.

@Grimlock the build trace you added shows that you work under Windows; this may explain that some development tools or libraries are missing. Maybe should you try to develop within WSL? Many development tools or libraries come out of the box or can be easily installed with apt.

@prog-fh yes, you are right. I think this problem may be caused by my old openssl version. So, I'll try it. Thanks.
